# Replace msg.value with some hardcoded value

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I have a smart contract(solidity) function as follows:-

```
    function incrementAttendance(uint _workerId) onlyOwner public payable{
        workerList[_workerId].attendanceValue = workerList[_workerId].attendanceValue+1;
        workerList[_workerId].recipient.transfer(msg.value);

    }
```

I want to transfer 10 Wei from some account to another account, the address of which(receiver) is stored in 'recipient' variable. Using msg.value prompts me to explicitly specify an amount on Remix IDE but I wish to specify the amount as part of the function call.

I tried:-
`workerList[_workerId].recipient.transfer(10);`

But the transaction is reverted at runtime. Solidity version 0.8.14 is used.
Kindly Help!!

Answer (score 0):

`msg.value` reflects the ETH value sent of the transaction executing your function (in this case `incrementAttendance()`).

You can hardcode the value 10 to be sent to `workerList[_workerId].recipient` but it's going to fail if your contract doesn't hold at least 10 wei at the time of executing this function.

---

What I'm assuming is that you want to hardcode the amount that the user sends while executing your `incrementAttendance()` function.

Unfortunately that's not possible from the smart contract because of the order of actions:

1. User creates, signs and broadcasts a transaction with some `value` defined by them. At this point, your contract has no idea that the user is planning to interact with it.
2. The transaction waits in the mempool until a miner/validator includes it in a block.
3. Only when the block producer executes the transaction, it decreases the sender's balance by their specified `value`, and then executes your contract function.

You can build your frontend app in a way that recommends the user to send some specific ETH `value` - and then validate in your contract if the received ETH `value` is what the contract expects.

Keep in mind that users can interact with your contract directly or through another frontend, or they can update the recommended value by your frontend, ... so you should always **validate** the received amount in your contract. But it's not technically possible to **set** an unchangeable for them.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for your help and clear explanation:)